# Update mysql value on browser closed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, browser

I have been going crazy over how to solve this problem, so if anyone out there could offer a solution, that would be absolutely fantastic...

Basically I am building a web site in PHP/MySQL and when a member logs in, their status in the database is set online=1, which means when other people search for them on the site, they see this person is currently online...

When the user logs out via the web site, I reset their status in the database to be online=0, so when people search for them on the site, they see that person as being offline....

That's all kool until you get to the point when the user closes their browser...there is no way I can think of that I can update the MySQL db to set their online=0, that is offline, at that particular point....I have done lots of research on this topic and so far haven't found a decent solution to the problem...

Any suggestions would be most welcome...thank you

Regards,
F2F

Comment: ajax perhaps. Pulse db with php script ? Who says they are even in front of their computer anymore, versus eating some ice cream, and off to the movies

Comment: Everytime he does something in your app (load a page...), you know that he is online. And if he doesn't do anything for a few minutes, he is offline. So just save the last time he did something and then check if it isn't so long.

Comment: Can you you onbeforeunload to fire an event to a javascript function, then use ajax to make a call to update the db?

Comment: if you do it with ajax the server will have to handle an extreme amount of data. i would save the last action timestamp and output the users which where active within the last 5 minutes.

Comment: extreme amount of data. really. Chances are they get bored and leave

Comment: other solution: use websockets and a websocketserver. Create a connection when your page is loaded. if a client disconnects from your server... he closed the tab or window. if this works for you depends on the amount of users and your ressources

Comment: I think i would just add an idle status so whenever the user was inactive for x amount of minutes then just set their status to idle. It's probably be easier that way